# replace page number using Regular Expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have a URL as Follow:

```
http://example.com/category/news/page/2/
```

I need to replace any number that comes at the end of URL which represents page number.
If possible which I think it is, I want to use regular expression in case the domain changes, the code still works.

I am also using PHP ...

Could help me with a proper RegEx?

Comment: What do you have so far and why does it need to be a regex?

Comment: Because this URL is not static and can be anything.

For Example the url might be 
`code http://example.com/category/news/data/page/2/ code`

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find The Answer:

```
string.replace(/\/page\/[0-9]+/, '/page/' + pageNum);
```

pageNum can be any variable to replace the page number

Comment: Thanks to notify me about that
I have added the JavaScript tag

Comment: previously it was `string.replace(/\/page\/[0-9]?/, '/page/' + pageNum);`

but I think the edited version is more correct